# What is the meaning of the smoking hair in Yellowbeard?

Tags: props, yellowbeard

I have watched [*Yellowbeard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowbeard) countless times and tried to place a meaning on the smoking hair ends used twice in the film. I have heard reference to an inside joke amongst the cast and crew, but never a definitive answer. Another forum suggests the answer may have died with Graham Chapman.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but "smoking hair", "Yellowbeard", and pirate movie, all remind me of Blackbeard the pirate, who used to board ships with burning matches in his beard to seam more sinister and intimidating.